# Boost, проверка даты

Tags: c++, boost

Есть дата paydate в строковом типе в формате YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss. Как через boost можно проверить, что эта дата наступает не раньше чем через сутки? То есть, примерно как-то так:

`if ((boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time() + boost::gregorian::days(1)) >= (boost::posix_time::from_iso_extended_string(paydate)))`

Comment: Код почти рабочий, только для такого формата надо взять парсер `time_from_string`.

Comment: да, уже нашел. но как быть тогда с форматом YYYY-MM-DD, без времени? Только вручную проверять и "00:00:00" приплюсовывать?

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос, но можно пойти по следующему пути: из строки `YYYY-MM-DD` получаем тип`date`, у него есть метод `to_tm`, который автоматически выставит нули для времени. А дальше получаем `ptime` из `ptime_from_tm`.